# How can I change existing token in the authtoken of django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Saving fails:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

token = Token.objects.get(user=user1)
token.key = '1'
token.save()
```

gives

> IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "authtoken_token_user_id_key"

Comment: Please show us the content of token table, so we know the reason for duplicate data..

Comment: There is only one token right now
>>> Token.objects.all()
>>> [<Token: a3301...>]

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue today so I thought I should leave a response for future reference explaining why this happens.

The `key` column **is** the primary key of the `Token` table.

If you edit a model instance, when you call the `save()` django has to figure whether it has to do an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`. It does so by looking for an existing row (using the primary key) in the database, since you just changed the primary key it won't find it and will assume it has to insert a new row. Since you already have a row for that user and the user_id column has a unique constraint the insert will fail.

An example with the corresponding generated sql.

```
>>> t = Token.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(id=1))
>>> t.key
u'b0750c801a1b075051ed084841f3001bb55dd1f1'
>>> t.key = t.generate_key()
'cafb2efb9b26912d60fc5a0a75b2b7ba0348a2ec'
t.save()
```

That `save()` call renders

```
SELECT (1) AS "a"
  FROM "authtoken_token"
  WHERE "authtoken_token"."key" = 'cafb2efb9b26912d60fc5a0a75b2b7ba0348a2ec'
  LIMIT 1;
INSERT
  INTO "authtoken_token" ("key", "user_id", "created")
  VALUES ('cafb2efb9b26912d60fc5a0a75b2b7ba0348a2ec', 1, '2014-03-18 21:48:30.434677+00:00');
```

There it's clear that the `SELECT` is looking for a row with the edited token (cafb2efb9b26912d60fc5a0a75b2b7ba0348a2ec).

**Solution**:

I guess in this specific case you can just delete the old `Token` instance and create a new one (in a single transaction), and it will auto generate the key for you, something like:

```
token.delete()
Token.objects.create(user=user1)
```

Note that this is an issue at the ORM level, you can avoid deleting/inserting and just change the value of that row but not using on the `save()` method.

Using the `update()` method is a good option as mariodev suggested, you'll need to manually generate the token (se above how I did it) and yes it that will change the primary key, the key column, but that's what you wanted in the first place :)

Answer (score 14):

Seems like this would work:

```
Token.objects.filter(user=user1).update(key='1')
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it works, but it changes primary key. I think it's not a good idea. So I created my own Token model and add new authentication.

Comment: @nmb.ten I'm lost, what exactly you need to change?

Answer (score 2):

This sample code work for me and update token in database:

```
t = Token.objects.filter(user=user1)
new_key = t[0].generate_key()
t.update(key=new_key)
```